# Trying to return values looped in a list, but can't get it using return, but print displays it

Tags: python-2.7

```
def dectoBin(n):
    for num in n:
        if num == 0:
            return ''
        else:
            return dectoBin(num/2) + str(num % 2)
```

Please can anyone help out?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: im writing a function that converts a lists of base 10 numbers to binary. but cannot loop through each value in the list using the return

Comment: You seem to think n is both an iterable and a number.

Comment: n is meant to accept a list. then converts each value in the list into binary numbers. please bear with me. I just started learning Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
def dectoBin(num):
    if num == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return dectoBin(num/2) + str(num % 2)
```

This is how recursion works. You don't that for loop in your code.

**EDIT:**

```
def dectoBin(num):
    if num == 0:
        return '0'
    elif num == 1:
        return '1'
    else:
        return dectoBin(num/2) + str(num % 2)

for i in range(257):
    print(dectoBin(i))
```

I've updated the code so that 0 can also be considered. Also note that if you want convert up to and including 256 you need to 257 in range.

Comment: @DeepSpace, are you trolling me? It is working. I've just tested it. `dectoBin(8)` gives `1000`, decToBin(15) gives `1111` etc.

Comment: Sorry, missed the fact this question is tagged with Python 2.7 in which `/` is floor division. On Python 3 one must use `//` or convert the result to `int`.

Comment: @Nurzhan how can i implement a code that runs through a range of numbers say range(0, 256) and gives me the individual binary conversion . thank you

Comment: @DeepSpace how can i implement a code that runs through a range of numbers say range(0, 256) and gives me the individual binary conversion . thank you

Comment: @Dolapo If it helped you can accept the answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never gets past the first value in `n` because you `return`.  Plus, your recursive call passes a number, not a list.

The clearest solution is to have one function to go through the list, converting the values and gathering the results, and a second to just convert a single number.

Comment: the thing is i cannot go through the list using the return cos it doesnt get past the first value. is there anyother way i can do it ,Thanks